# Merging typescript "module" across multiple files

Tags: typescript

With the following typescript code I can access `Alphabet.alpha.one` and `Alphabet.beta.two`

```
export module Alphabet {
    export module alpha {
        export const one = 1
    }
}

export module Alphabet {
    export module beta {
        export const two = 2
    }
}

console.log(Alphabet.alpha.one)
```

However If I split these "export module's" into two files, how can I get the same access that "Alphabet" has in one file?

I've tried something akin to this:

```
import "./Alphabet.alpha"
import "./Alphabet.beta"
```

But this doesn't import anything. And if I define `Alphabet` through one of these, it only has that one prop `Alpha` or `Beta`.

How can I split two deep "module" into separate files, yet be able to access the full object through another file.

---

Update:

This works but the typing is "any", which is not desirable.

```
const Alphabet = Object.assign({},
    require('./Alphabet.alpha'),
    require('./Alphabet.beta'),
)
```

Comment: You are currently exporting internal modules (aka namespaces) inside ES modules, these cannot be auto-merged. Either use namespaces (without `export`, `import` at file top-level) or if modules are needed, you would have to manually merge them somehow and then just export this merge result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried namespaces without export, it only returns types and not actual value.

Comment: [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=12&pln=2&pc=18#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBANjAFiARhALkgN4CwAUEpUhAB4wD2AToaJLAsiBtseVf9TpNC8esCiExyALxIAjHyoBfcirLlW0OIlTdcBXhSq0GzJJvY68+EIYHGhZ0eML4A7vSSyATIspq1cmcoejQIADo0egBzAAp0LH18cOsQcPd6AEokAHocpG8gA) is an example, this namespace is accessible on the global scope.

Comment: Yep, this I knew already. What the question is asking, is how can you but both of those namespace declarations into two separate files, then import them together again.